# Swagger UI ignores query-param "url=" and opens PetStore instead

Tags: swagger-ui

After updating Swagger UI from 3.x to 4.x, loading my custom schema via a parameter in the application-url breaks.

Before `https://example.com/swagger/index.html?url=https://example.com/docs/simrws.yaml` would load my custom specs. Now that just loads the default example `Swagger Petstore`.

There are no errors on the console. The [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) say, that the fourth method to configure Swagger UI is to use URL-params.

Answer (score 1):

A breaking [security-feature](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4872) was added in `V4.1.3`:

```
root@server:/opt/swagger-ui-git# git diff v4.1.2 v4.1.3 src/core/index.js
diff --git a/src/core/index.js b/src/core/index.js
index 677e3786..621b095f 100644
--- a/src/core/index.js
+++ b/src/core/index.js
@@ -77,6 +77,7 @@ export default function SwaggerUI(opts) {

+    queryConfigEnabled: false,

@@ -108,7 +109,7 @@ export default function SwaggerUI(opts) {


-  let queryConfig = parseSearch()
+  let queryConfig = opts.queryConfigEnabled ? parseSearch() : {}
```

You will find that mentioned in the docs linked above.

Edit the file `dist/swagger-initializer.js` to add the following line under `url:...petstore...` to revert to the old behavior:

```
queryConfigEnabled: true,
```

As this was a **security fix**, there might be a better way than to just to revert to the old behavior.

Comment: I believe there's no need to change `src/core/index.js`. Instead, you can add `queryConfigEnabled: true` to the config options in the `SwaggerUIBundle({ ...})` constructor (which typically resides in the [`swagger-initializer.js`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/swagger-initializer.js) or `index.html`).

Comment: That is absolutely the right way to do that. I will modify my answer accordingly. Thanks! My way would only work, if you'd build a new distribution-package afterwards. But that would require a full development-environment. So let's not do that :D